# How to check if user meta field is empty in conditional else statement

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta

Hello all I have a custom post type set up for my wordpress site within this custom post type i have a meta box with about 11 meta fields that I have added programatically. What I would like to do is check if one of the fields (which i have programmed to be a radio box)has a value if it does i would like to display the value of the field. If not then i would like to echo out the word Available. This is what I have been trying so far:

```
<?php

 $consignment= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'availability', true); 

if (empty ($consignment)) {
    echo "avaliable";
} elseif ($consignment > 1) {
    echo "$consignment";
} 
?>
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Just use 'else' without any test instead of 'elseif'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the trick?

```
$consignment= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'availability', true); 

if ($consignment == '') {
// code to run if the above is empty, eg.
  echo "avaliable";

} else {
    // else the code, eg.
    echo $consignment;
}
```